# Changing background color of a class in succesion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two classes of elements. The idea is that when I mouseover the first element that has the class `box`, the first element of that has the class `blue` changes its background color. The Background color of other elements that have the class `blue should remain unchanged.

```js
function changeColor(color) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("blue");
  x[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
  x[1].style.backgroundColor = color;
  x[2].style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function returnColor() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("blue");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onmouseout="returnColor()" onmouseover="changeColor('green')"></div>
<div class="box" onmouseout="returnColor()" onmouseover="changeColor('yellow')"></div>
<div class="box" onmouseout="returnColor()" onmouseover="changeColor('red')"></div><br>
<br>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Onmouseout the same element retains it s background color. Then when I mouseover the second element of box class the second element of blue class changes its background color. Onmouseout the same element retains its background color and so on. I know I can do this if I add an ID to each of the elements but I am specifically interested in doing it using classes only.

As you can see from my attempt I only managed to change background of an entire class instead of each element separately as it was intended.

Comment: Just a question, why are you trying to achieve this with JS? CSS is a solution for this problem.

Comment: Agreed, you can easily do this with css `:hover` selector.

Comment: Yes i know i could use :hover selector, but i am a javascript novice and i was looking for javascript solution, and the one i got from Hive7 was both puzzling and rewarding.Hive7 if it s not too mush of a hassle could you please elaborate more on your code starting from line

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 'this' as a second parameter.
You should then get the current element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do is use the index of the first element group and pass it to the second set, this is relatively easy and all you have to do is cycle through the elements and attach the events in the javascript so you can maintain the index easily. Shown below:

https://jsfiddle.net/fkakt7wc/7/

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("blue");
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].index = i;
    y[i].onmouseover = function () {
        x[this.index].style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute("color");
    }
    y[i].onmouseout = function () {
        x[this.index].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hive7 could you please elaborate more on your code, especially from line y[i].index = i; the meaning of the statement; is 'index' a property?And also x[this.index].style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute("color"); why did you use 'this', when should it be used and why did you use getAttribute("color"); instead of just 'color'.The questions may seem dumb, bear in mind i m a novice.Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan the point of the code is that "i" is a local variable so inside the function it will be the last iteration of "i" after the for loop is finished. To counter this we store the index as a property of the element so we can easily call it. The point of using get attribute color is so that we don't have to use a specific case for each element. The point fo the `x[this.index]` is in order to have the same index within the two groups for both elements